# Using Hamachi to develop XNA on one PC

Tags: networking, xna, vmware, hamachi

I'm currently trying to develop a network game for XNA (LAN only as no desire to release), however I only own 1 PC.

I've been trying many different things but all seem to have failed. I'm running VMWare Player with a Win7 Prof image (with vs2008 + XNA 3.1 installed) from my main PC (Win 7, everything installed).

I've installed Hamachi on both but Games For Windows Live seems to refuse to use the hamachi connection (even though it's at the top of the preferred list).

If anyone has any advice on what I could try next, or how to get Hamachi working, I'd be extremely grateful.

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get either another PC or an Xbox 360. You can't do multiple multiplayer game instances on 1 PC.